# TinyMCE and IE 9 Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce

I have TinyMCE 4.0 in the page and when I select the text and try to paste it via <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>, I get an error message saying that "Clipboard access not possible." This happens in IE8/9. However the same works fine in Chrome. Is there any workaround for this to get this working in IE?

---

**Bounty:**

I've tried resetting all IE settings (via Internet Options->Advanced->Reset All...) on two different computers, both running IE9, and one has the problem while the other does not.

Ultimately, I need to be able to paste formatted text (often with bullets or numeric lists and such) into TinyMCE and have it format them correctly. For this, I'm using the *paste* plugin, which seems to be throwing the error.

Comment: @Travesty3 Did you already check if CTRL+V works in your IE with the TinyMCE [live demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php)?

Comment: @Enzino: No, I haven't tried that. Good suggestion...I will try it on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you're using an older TinyMCE 4 version, so in my opinion you should first do an upgrade to the [latest version](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/changelog/?type=tinymce) (4.0.3).
I've checked the source code of such version and I've found no trace of the `Clipboard access not possible` error message, which seems instead to be present in an earlier version of the `tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js` file, and only for Internet Explorer:

```
e.ie ? o.on("init", function () {
   var e = o.dom;
   o.dom.bind(o.getBody(), "paste", function (n) {
      var r;
      if (n.preventDefault(), a() && e.doc.dataTransfer) 
         return c(e.doc.dataTransfer.getData("Text")), t;
      var i = u();
      e.bind(i, "paste", function (e) {
         e.stopPropagation(), r = !0
      });
      var s = o.selection.getRng(),
          f = e.doc.body.createTextRange();
      if (f.moveToElementText(i.firstChild), f.execCommand("Paste"), d(), !r) 
         return o.windowManager.alert("Clipboard access not possible."), t;
      var p = i.firstChild.innerHTML;
      o.selection.setRng(s), l(p)
   })
}
```

Not being able to find an unminified version of this script, I can't say why such code fails, nor can I explain why it works only on one of your's computers.

Comment: Perhaps. My version just says `4.0 (2013-06-13)`. Perhaps that's 4.0.0. I will try updating on Monday and see if that fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer's Tools menu, choose Internet Options.
Click the Security tab.
Click Trusted Sites.
Click the Sites... button.
Type your domain name (for example, widgetdesigns.com) in the first field, then click Add.
Unselect the checkbox that says Require server verification (https:) for all sites in this zone.
Click OK to apply your change.
Back on the Security tab, confirm that Trusted Sites is still selected, then click the Custom Level button.
Scroll down the Security section (near the bottom) and check the Disable box below Allow Programmatic clipboard access. (Checking this box will disable the access alert only for sites in your Trusted Sites list.)
Click OK then OK again to apply your changes.
What about this? Does this work?

Comment: Tried this too. Same problem.

Comment: Then I guess it might be some other issue! These were the only two ways that hit me. Sorry.